# Running an x86_64 File on aarch64 not working

Tags: linux, arm, qemu, elf

I have been searching and trying a lot of things for a while now.

Setup:

1. Kali Linux as Virtiual Maschine using UTM on MAC M2
   `uname -a`
   Linux kali 6.1.0-kali9-arm64 #1 SMP Debian 6.1.27-1kali1 (2023-05-12) aarch64 GNU/Linux
2. Want to execute a file named 'my-file'
   `file my-file` my-file: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=9fdbc145689e0fb79cb7291203431012ae8e1911, stripped

I found [this article](https://www.kali.org/docs/arm/x86-on-arm/) and follow the instructions. After restarting Kali `pwsh` Command is working. For my-file I still get the following error: `zsh: exec format error: ./my-file`

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found a solution.

I tried `qemu-x86_64-static ./my-file` and got the error

> error while loading shared libraries: libfribidi.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

and similar ones. I executed the following commands (each according to the error message)

> sudo apt-get install libfuse2:amd64 
> sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1:amd64 
> sudo apt-get install libx11-6:amd64
> sudo apt-get install libharfbuzz-dev:amd64
> sudo apt-get install libfribidi-dev:amd64

Now the command `qemu-x86_64-static ./my-file` is working.